# grab all selected answers from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grap all selected values from a page and push them into an array.

I have tried the following:

```js
values = $.map(answers ,function(option) {
    return option.value;
 });




//it was working at somepoint, but apparently not anymore. is there a easier way to get this accomplished?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">a</option>
          <option value="2">b</option>
          <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field select2">
       <p>q2</p>
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="2">a</option>
          <option value="5">b</option>
          <option value="7">c</option>
          <option value="10">d</option>
          <option value="12">e</option>
        </select>
        <!-- <label>Materialize Select</label> -->
      </div>
      <div class="input-field select3">
       <p>What do you Find More Interesting?</p>
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>a</option>
          <option value="1">b</option>
          <option value="3">c</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: `$(form).serializeArray()`

Comment: what is `answers`?